# Is the fake ice cream on top of an ice cream truck called an "ice cream figure"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image: truck with fake ice cream cone on top]

My daughter looked at the above picture and she said "**a truck with a fake ice cream on its head**".

What is it called?

Is it called "**an ice cream figure**"?

I am not sure because it seems like "**figure**" is used for people or animals

Comment: Who is the audience?  For a child I would say something like "a huge ice cream cone".

Comment: The audience is anyone who watches *American Pickers*. What do they call a little boy holding a giant doughnut? Mobil's Pegasus is a *sign*. Doughnuts and fake ice cream are *displays* (designed to lure in customers)? : *"an eye-catching arrangement by which something is exhibited"*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd say "a fake ice cream" is a good description.  A "mock ice cream cone" is also possible.

I'd be happy to just say "a giant ice cream cone on the roof" and allow the context to imply that it isn't *real* ice cream.

In more "grown-up" language you might call it a model, or a display.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe *a truck with a huge ice-cream cone sculpture on its roof.*

The top of a closed motor vehicle is its *roof*.

The word *cone* is needed because it's not just a blob of ice cream:
[M-W *ice-cream cone*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ice-cream%20cone)
: a thin crisp edible cone for holding ice cream
**also : one filled with ice cream**

Comment: I think ‘cone’ would be implied by the context, anyway — and by the article (‘_**an**_ ice cream’).

Comment: @gidds I think I've seen ice cream  trucks with a model of a cup of ice cream. OTOH,  it's probably not usually necessary to distinguish cup and cone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "figure" is wrong, but I would say "a figure of an ice cream cone." In general, one doesn't say "an X figure".

In Merriam-Webster, definition 3a for figure is:

> : the graphic representation of a form especially of a person or
> geometric entity
>
> [example:] a figure of a girl with pigtails

By this definition, you could argue that a sculpture cannot be a figure. It also supports your sense that we tend to use it with people. However, I think the main distinction between a figure of something and a picture/sculpture of something is that we (optionally) use the word "figure" if the representation is more generic or abstract, just as in the case of the ice cream cone. I also googled "a figure of a car" (with quotes) and got some hits. So there is some support for my intuition that it doesn't *have* to refer to people or geometric objects.

Comment: "Figure" almost always means a two-dimensional drawing, though, not a three-dimensional model or sculpture.